# Передача css значений с объекта js

Tags: javascript

Задача такая "Надо написать функцию которая будет принимать элемент, css правило, и его значения. Устанавливать элементу css правило с значением"

```
  function setCssAttribute(element, property, value) {
  cube.style[property] = value;
}

  setCssAttribute(cube, 'backgroundColor', 'black');
  setCssAttribute(cube, 'height', '175');

document.querySelector('#width_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    setCssAttribute()
});
```

Comment: функция правильно написана, в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: вы вызываете функцию `setCssAttribute` без параметров, попробуйте внутри обработчика `onclick` вызвать функцию так `setCssAttribute(this, 'width', '175px');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши ошибки

```
1  function setCssAttribute(element, property, value) {
2    cube.style[property] = value;
3  }
4  
5    setCssAttribute(cube, 'backgroundColor', 'black');
6    setCssAttribute(cube, 'height', '175');
7  
8  document.querySelector('#width_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
9      setCssAttribute()
10 });
```

1. Строка 2: переменная `cube` не обозначена, элементом является первый аргумент функции и называется `element`
2. Строка 5: в функцию первым аргументом вместо элемента отсылается `undefined`, так как переменная `cube` не обозначена.
3. Строка 6: в функцию первым аргументом вместо элемента отсылается `undefined`, так как переменная `cube` не обозначена.
4. Строка 9: в функцию не передаются никакие аргументы, тем самым `setCssAttribute` вновь выкинет исключение в виде отсутствия элемента (`undefined`).

А вот правильный код

```js
function setCssAttribute(element, property, value) {
  element.style[property] = value;
}

document.querySelector('#width_btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setCssAttribute(this, 'backgroundColor', 'black');
  setCssAttribute(this, 'height', '175px');
});
```

```html
<div id="width_btn" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:gray;"></div>
```

`this` является элементом, которому было присвоено событие `click`. его и отправляем в функцию первым аргументом.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так. Если нужны будут пояснения - пишите

```js
element = document.querySelector('#width_btn');

setCssProperty(element, 'width', '175px');
setCssProperty(element, 'height', '175px');

element.addEventListener(
  'click',
  clickHandler,
  false
);

function setCssProperty(element, property, value) {
  element.style[property] = value;
}

function clickHandler(event){
    setCssProperty(event.target, 'width', '100px');
    setCssProperty(event.target, 'height', '100px');  
}
```

```css
#width_btn {  
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="width_btn">Click me!</div>
```